# Issue with binding data from collection list in data edit window

Tags: c#, xaml

I created new collection  list (Observable Collection), from two different SQL table, which are in one-to-many relationship. I have table with products and the other is Bids table only with code of product. New collection have related code with product name. After that, I listed new collection in DataGridView, properly.
The problem is, when I click on row and want to edit data from row, in new window, I can not get that Name of Product, as pre-entered value. It shows other variables which I have on table Bids, but no Name from Products table, just to be shown.

Comment: Welcome on SO. I'm afraid your question cannot be answered in its current state and it might get downvoted soonish. Please provide code for your problem and check on SOs How-To-Ask-guide to increase your chance of getting an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am afraid that there would be too much code. This is my first post here and I don't know how much code I can put?

Comment: Solved, thank you anyway, I discovered small bug in my code